# Gnome Themes: Why the color of the calendar window is not according to the theme?

Tags: gnome

Why the color of the calendar window is not according to the theme? Whatever theme I use It remains the same. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please see the above link for the screenshot.

Comment: Themes that I have tested are listed below:

Comment: MacOS 5.2, Adapata, Adapta-Eta.

Comment: This Problem doesn't occur with any dark theme.

Comment: Currently, I am using the Adapta Shell Theme. And in  ./themes folder, I am not getting the Adapta CSS file. There is no folder named  Adapta.

Comment: please do not fill the comment section,edit any new information into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PRATAP'S method for changing third-party css but your problem is with Adwaita,which is now a part of GTK 3+, so you can't simply change the CSS of Adwaita theme in /usr/share/themes.You should wait for the next update of the theme.

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through "MacOS 5.2" shell theme..

[image: theme sample screenshot]

It is missing the "background-color:" entry and thus taking the color from resources.. which is that dark/light gray color.

so search for the below content from the shell theme css file

```
.calendar {
   margin-bottom: 1em }
```

add your preferred color, for example:

```
.calendar {
    background-color: rgba(3, 117, 248, 0.6);
    margin-bottom: 1em; }
```

the weather section is also missing causing the dark/light gray..

for this, a better way is to grab the "weather" part from resources `gnome-shell.css` file. for example, I have copy pasted the below content and edit the colors as I wish.

```
/* Weather */
.weather-button {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: #eeeeec;
  background-color: rgba(3, 117, 248, 0.6);
  border-color: #2b2b2b;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  icon-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px; }
  .weather-button:focus {
    color: #eeeeec;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    icon-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(27, 106, 203, 0.6); }
  .weather-button:hover {
    color: #eeeeec;
    background-color: rgba(3, 117, 248, 0.6);
    border-color: #2b2b2b;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    icon-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  .weather-button:active {
    color: #eeeeec;
    background-color: rgba(3, 117, 248, 0.8);
    border-color: #191919;
    text-shadow: none;
    icon-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none; }
  .weather-button .weather-box {
    spacing: 10px; }
  .weather-button .weather-header-box {
    spacing: 6px; }
  .weather-button .weather-header {
    color: #878787;
    font-weight: bold; }
    .weather-button .weather-header.location {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 10pt; }
  .weather-button .weather-grid {
    spacing-rows: 6px;
    spacing-columns: 12px; }
  .weather-button .weather-forecast-time {
    color: #a6a69b;
    font-feature-settings: "tnum";
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em; }
  .weather-button .weather-forecast-icon {
    icon-size: 2.18em; }
  .weather-button .weather-forecast-temp {
    font-weight: bold; }
```

The result is

[image: same photo as before with different colours]

So nothing is limited here for the customization, you may adapt different contents as you wish taking the source from default gnome-shell's resource or any one as you wish.

You may raise the missing part issue to the authors of the themes if you wish to to correct them in their next update.

Comment: Great!, But if I change the color of the calendar to white, it hides the numbers in the calendar. So I customized that also and now it looks great.