# How to know the names of Gnome shell components?

Tags: gnome, themes

I want to create a custom theme for the Gnome shell. My question is not about creating a theme for the applications. Instead, my question is about styling the top bar, popup trays, dock icons-- which are part of the Gnome shell. Where to get a full documentation of the CSS name, id and class name of those components?

I have tried looking at the stylesheets of some themes, but I cannot figure out which name is associated with which component. For example, this is a part of the stylesheet from [**Transparent shell theme 3.7**](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1203425/) from [gnome-look.org](https://gnome-look.org) :

```css
stage {
    font-family: sfns display, product sans, helvetica, source sans pro, segoe ui, nokia pure text, segoe ui, ubuntu,oxygen, cantarell, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #efefef;}

/* links */
.shell-link {
    color: #0000ff;
    text-decoration: underline;}

.shell-link:hover {
    color: #999b9b;}

/*medium 12 pt*/
.nm-dialog-item,
.calendar-month-label,
.calendar-day,
.datemenu-today-button,
.message-list-section-title,
.message-content,
.notification-banner .message-title,
.notification-banner .message-content,
.app-well-menu, {
font-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Design

Comment: I have already visited that site, but I haven't got any kind of help regarding the CSS names. It just speaks about the design, not about customization.

Comment: you need to search for the parts for example, "status-area" or "status area" etc.. calendar, top bar, show-apps, show apps like that.. I think the css file hardly it has around 2000 lines.. in which main title's are `/* title */`

Answer (score 6):

You may wish to download the source of the gnome-shell package with the below command

```
apt-get source gnome-shell
```

Then navigate to the widgets directory.. for example:

`../gnome-shell_3.36.3.orig/gnome-shell-3.36.3/data/theme/gnome-shell-sass/widgets/`

[image]

Comment: By the way `apt-get source gnome-shell` is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the help. From those stylesheets, I am somewhat able to get some clues for the components. But, is there any documentation which can tell about the supported and unsupported attributes? I am asking this because although the stylesheets are written using CSS, there are many non-standard attributes and values.

Comment: I never gone through the source code for theming changes.. But I think this is the best option source code -->> widgets... But by interacting with the elements in the css file. elements in the sense main commented titiles like `/* Top bar */` `/* Calendar */` you will reach the element. Then your knowledge on the css will make it easier to customize like on hover, clicked, active, inactive etc..

Comment: see this for example: https://askubuntu.com/q/1260568/739431 OP is looking for calendar and weather part.. So my concentration on calendar and weather in the css narrowed the search limited to those few lines only out of 2000 lines..